# Wordpress login API Rest

Tags: wordpress, api

Tenho um cliente que utiliza `Woordpress` e `WooCommerce`, e tenho que fazer um app mobile da loja virtual dele, o meu problema está no LOGIN do cliente.

Olhei diversas `API` Rest de desenvolvedores e nenhuma tem o login do usuário, ou seja terei que fazer isso na mão. Meu maior problema agora é que não sei como fazer esse serviço rest ficar acessível através de uma URL por exemplo:

```
minhaloja.com.br/api/usuario
```

Essa página tem que ser criada na instalação do plugin.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Já pesquisou a WP REST API? http://v2.wp-api.org/ tem autenticação de usuários sim.

Comment: Oi Ricardo, eu tinha pesquisado, porém era 03:00 da manhã e não vi esse link, fui meio que direto no GIT. Vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado.

Comment: Então Ricardo, eu preciso de um serviço que envio login e senha e ele me retorna caso exista os dados do cliente e caso não exista um false, porém não acho isso.

Comment: O login do cliente é um login de usuário do WordPress?

Comment: Uma possível forma seria tentar acessar uma API qualquer, que exija autenticação; se o usuário não estiver autenticado, deve dar erro 403, ou coisa semelhante.

Comment: Sim, o cliente é um usuario do Wordpress(clientes do WooCommerce). Achei  dois plugins aqui que resolvem o meu problema são eles:  
JSON API e JSON API USER acessando fica assim: http://localhost/Apps/wordpress/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=admin&password=admin&insecure=cool. De certa forma, alguem sabe fazer isso? Uma forma de eu criar uma url e essa url nao cair na "pagina nao encontrada" do WP?

Answer (score -2):

Cara.. para você autenticar no wordpress via a api você poderá fazer de algumas formas..

1. Cookie Authentication
2. OAuth Authentication
3. Basic Authentication (caso não precise de um nível de segurança muito alto)
4. JWT Authentication

Tirando o primeiro o restante você precisará instalar plugins.. Basta pesquisar rapidamente no google que vc encontra.

Eu aconselho você utlizar o JWT.. é fácil de entender e tem um nível bom de segurança.